# How do you set the namespace AND property value of a ksoap2 PropertyInfo?

Tags: android, azure, ksoap2

I am using ksoap2 to operate an azure web service, and the service uses the namespace

http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays

which means some of the inner elements look like

```
<n:string xmlns:n="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">value</n:string>
```

Now I want to send strings of this type but if you add a property to a `SoapObject` using the `PropertyInfo` class, I can't find a way to set the actual value, so I would have

```
<n:string xmlns:n="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
```

On the other hand, I can add a name/value pair directly, but then I can't set the namespace:

```
<string>value</string>
```

Is there a way to do this without implementing a lot of `KvmSerializable` classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PropertyInfo` has a number of accessible members, like `PropertyInfo.name`, but it also has a `setValue(Object)` method.  This can be used.